# ClamAV update failure. Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, clamav

I am using the 4.42 GUI version which is the newest. The antivirus engine is .97.6 also the newest.
The problem is my antivirus definitions are out of date. When I run

```
sudo freshclam
```

Here is the error:

```
ClamAV update process started at Thu Nov 22 21:18:49 2012
Connecting via localhost
connect_error: getsockopt(SO_ERROR): fd=4 error=111: Connection refused
Can't connect to port 8118 of host localhost (IP: 127.0.0.1)
WARNING: Can't download main.cvd from db.local.clamav.net
Trying again in 5 secs...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure clamav-freshclam
```

should do the trick!!